# Ayuda con estilos de un dropdown en menu en react

Tags: css, reactjs

He estado teniendo un problema con la implementación de un dropdown en un componente de estructura de arbol en react pero al tratar de moverme sobre las opciones del dropdown empieza a verse unas transiciones entre el fondo y el menú del dropdown

[image: Error]

Recree de forma simplificada el error en el siguiente repositorio
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-hertz-bjcy5

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o idea que me puedan dar para poder solucionar este comportamiento.

Comment: Estuve revisando el código que tienes en codesandbox, pero parece que no funciona

Comment: Si efectivamente no se que pasó y no se mostraba, pero hice un cambio para que se pueda ver. gracias de antemano

Comment: Parece ser algún tipo de conflicto de estilos entre `reactstrap` y `react-sortable-tree`. Creo que deberías reportarlo en la página de alguno de los proyectos (o en ambos). En su defecto, entrar al código de ambos y tratar de arreglarlo por tu cuenta.